# Withdrawn patents

Tags: withdrawn

How can I find out when or why a patent by my Father was withdrawn?  I believe that he wrote a patent back in the 1960's that was withdrawn and resubmitted later by his employer.  He left the company to take a better offer at another aerospace corporation.  They were mad, and took his name off of the patent.  Then I believe that they resubmitted it later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Public Pair to review the *available* file history of any published application or issued, but because this was in the 1960 only basic information will be available. However, for a small fee, the USPTO can send you a copy of the full file history, which will likely have the information you are looking for.

If you don't have an application number (format NN/NNN,NNN) publication number (format YEAR/NNNNNNN) or issued patent number (format N,NNN,NNN) then you can look it up by searching by inventor name, assignee/owner name among other fields. The USPTO and Google Patents have good searches for this. [Links available here](http://www.patentsdemystified.com/patent-guide-resources/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. Adams for your help.  I will try Public Pair.  I have just sent an e-mail to USPTO asking them for the history file.  In the past they have told me that I have to go in person to a patent library in either Los Angeles or New Mexico.  This will mean travel for me.  If I can get the same information via Public Pair or paying a small fee, that would be much better.  If I am successful, I will share here.

Comment: Assuming you are able find the application on PAIR, you can order the file wrapper copy directly from there. I added an image to my post above that shows where this link should be.

Comment: You are a doll!  This graphic will really help me.  I will search PAIR today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PublicPair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) to retrieve the history of the patent. Do you have the patent number?

Comment: Yes Daniel it is the First Cal Tech Calculator Patent # 3,819,921 US which had a long and difficult time getting issued.  There were law suits with the Japanese.  My Dad was the scientist who wrote the original filing for this invention at Texas Instruments, but he accepted a job as Supervisor of R&D at Hughes Aircraft in 1967.  He worked on the Surveyor Project at Hughes in California.  So they must have pulled the filing and resubmitted a couple of times.  When it was finally issued in 1974, my Dad told my Mom "I just made TI a million dollars".  More like a billion!!!